# Custom post type sub-category pagination return error 404 on second page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have a custom query as follows:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'programme',
            'posts_per_page' => 11,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query'      => array(
                'relation' => 'AND', 
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'programme_category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array('video-on-demand')
                )
            ),
            'orderby'        => 'date',
            'order'          => 'DESC'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

and this my pagination:

```
$paginate_links = paginate_links(array(
    'base'    => str_replace(999999999, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link(999999999))),
    'format'  => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total'   => $query->max_num_pages,
    'type'    => 'array',
    'prev_text' => 'Prev',
    'next_text' => 'Next'
));

if ($paginate_links) {
    foreach ($paginate_links as $page) {
        echo '<li class="list-inline-item">'. $page .'</li>';
    }
}
```

The issue now is that when clicked on the page 2 of the pagination it returns 404. The URL structure is like this:

http://[domain]/programme-category/video-on-demand/page/2/

Could anyone help me with this. I have searched & test all solutions but yet still the error persist.

Comment: What template are you running this in? These errors are usually a result of unwanted interactions between a custom query and the template's default WP_Query object.

Comment: Hi @ChrisCox I'm using Elementor Theme Builder, but I also have created a custom shortcode which having the same issue.

Comment: Is this the main loop for the page you're displaying it on?